# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy - Cannot deploy artifacts when Maven is in offline mode

Tags: maven

I run project deploy in Maven project and get the problem as below:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project iris: Cannot deploy artifacts when Maven is in offline mode -> [Help 1]
```

Could you help me figure out this problem?

Comment: Plz share ur pom.xml & settings.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is configured in offline mode, that means Maven will not try to connect to any remote repository. Therefore, the `maven-deploy-plugin` cannot upload your jar.

Offline mode can be configured in two different ways :

- launching Maven with the [`-o` flag](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-offline-option). Maven is offline only for this execution.
- setting the `offline` attribute to `true` in the [`settings.xml` file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html). Maven is offline for all executions.

One of those two options must be enabled in your configuration and you must remove it for `maven-deploy-plugin` to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using IntelliJ and randomly started to get that error. It turns out that for some reason the setting 'Work offline' got enabled.

To turn it off, I had to go to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven` and uncheck the box 'Work offline'.

[maven work offline option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryXm7.png)